# SQL Management Studio shortcuts

Tags: sql, ssms

Using SQL 2014 Management studio and SQL Assistant 7.0.158.

When editing `sql` scripts in the Query window I get the following annoying behavior.
When the cursor is positioned before any text and hitting the tab key the cursor jumps the the top of the query window.
If I however hit the space bar once and then the Tab key the cursor jumps the required number of spaces.

Also when typing an open bracket there is an auto complete of the closing bracket witch I will like to disable.

I hope there is a customization setting for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can customize it from

```
Tools –> Options -> Environment –> Keyboard
```

If you wants to know more about keyboard shortcuts in sql, read [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ms174205).